# How to calculate the number of value between two extreme values?

Tags: r

I have a dataset that I need to calculate the recapture probability. I was thinking that if I sum the values that are 0 (species not recapture) between two event of capture 1 and divide this value by the number of potential capture (all the events of 1 plus all the events between the 1, so 0) would give me a probability of recapture.

E.g. if I have `1 1 0 1` this would be 1/4 = .25 so I would have a 25% chance of not recapturing a species. In another case, if I have `1 0 0 1` I would have 2/4 so 50% chance of recapturing this species. Finally, if I have `1 1 1 0`, this would be 0/3 so 0% of species that are not recaptured.

Is there a way to automate this in this dataset?

```
structure(list(y.2010 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), y.2011 = c(1, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), y.2012 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1), y.2013 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), y.2014 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), BANDFINAL = c("JP179", "JP197", 
"JP209", "JP2340", "JP3118", "JP3120", "JP3162", "JP3164", "JP3165", 
"JP3170", "JP3171")), .Names = c("y.2010", "y.2011", "y.2012", 
"y.2013", "y.2014", "BANDFINAL"), row.names = c(103L, 113L, 120L, 
125L, 140L, 142L, 151L, 153L, 154L, 156L, 157L), class = "data.frame")
```

Which prints this:

```
    y.2010 y.2011 y.2012 y.2013 y.2014 BANDFINAL
103      1      1      0      0      0     JP179
113      1      1      0      0      0     JP197
120      1      1      0      0      0     JP209
125      1      0      1      0      0    JP2340
140      1      1      0      0      0    JP3118
142      1      1      0      0      0    JP3120
151      1      1      1      1      0    JP3162
153      1      0      0      1      0    JP3164
154      1      0      0      1      0    JP3165
156      1      1      0      0      0    JP3170
157      1      1      1      0      0    JP3171
```

In the end, it's suppose to do this:

```
0
0
0
1/3
0
0
0
2/4
2/4
0
0
```

Thanks,

Comment: There's a big literature on capture-mark-recapture analysis to estimate capture probability.  Is there a reason not to use those tools, e.g. the [RMark package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RMark) ?   (Do you really have only a single capture history per species, and want to estimate recapture probability separately for every capture history?)

Comment: I really want to use it, but I don't understand what type of data I should have. I have this:

`structure(list(BAND = structure(1:6, .Label = c("HS816", 
"JP1049", "JP1095", "JP1200", "JP1386", "JP1395/P789"), class = "factor"), 
    Sex0 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("f", 
    "m"), class = "factor"), Mass = c(20.6, 20.3, 23.1, 20.6, 
    19.3, 20.8), ch = c("000000000010", "011101010000", "010100000100", 
    "011110010000", "010110011000", "011111110100")), .Names = c("BAND", 
"Sex0", "Mass", "ch"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame") `

Comment: People are telling me that RMark is complicated! So I think that I was just trying to find a way to estimate it very easily to have an idea. The help in R is not that helpful...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess @Ben is right, but I'm not familiar with this literacy and this question seems like fun to solve, so here's my `base` attempt on this using the vectorized `max.col` and `rowSums` functions in order to calculate the probabilities

```
indx <- max.col(df[-ncol(df)], ties.method = "last")
df$Prob <- (indx - rowSums(df[-ncol(df)])) / indx
df
#     y.2010 y.2011 y.2012 y.2013 y.2014 BANDFINAL      Prob
# 103      1      1      0      0      0     JP179 0.0000000
# 113      1      1      0      0      0     JP197 0.0000000
# 120      1      1      0      0      0     JP209 0.0000000
# 125      1      0      1      0      0    JP2340 0.3333333
# 140      1      1      0      0      0    JP3118 0.0000000
# 142      1      1      0      0      0    JP3120 0.0000000
# 151      1      1      1      1      0    JP3162 0.0000000
# 153      1      0      0      1      0    JP3164 0.5000000
# 154      1      0      0      1      0    JP3165 0.5000000
# 156      1      1      0      0      0    JP3170 0.0000000
# 157      1      1      1      0      0    JP3171 0.0000000
```

Comment: nice, what if we have a 0 in the first column though?

Comment: @jeremycg I don't think it's possible here, but it will be need a modification in that cast, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dplyr`.

First we `gather` the data into long format. Then we `group_by` band. Then we `summarise` the first and last catch, and the prob which is the number of 0s between first and last:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dat %>% gather(year, val, -BANDFINAL) %>%
        group_by(BANDFINAL) %>%
        summarise(first = min(which(val == 1)),
                  last = max(which(val == 1)),
                  prob = sum(val[first:last]==0)/(last - first +1))
Source: local data frame [11 x 4]

   BANDFINAL first  last      prob
       (chr) (int) (int)     (dbl)
1      JP179     1     2 0.0000000
2      JP197     1     2 0.0000000
3      JP209     1     2 0.0000000
4     JP2340     1     3 0.3333333
5     JP3118     1     2 0.0000000
6     JP3120     1     2 0.0000000
7     JP3162     1     4 0.0000000
8     JP3164     1     4 0.5000000
9     JP3165     1     4 0.5000000
10    JP3170     1     2 0.0000000
11    JP3171     1     3 0.0000000
```